# How do I use Multithread to iterate a list with many records

Tags: multithreading, listiterator, executors

I have a list with 200 records of an object. For each record in that list, I need to call an API REST (findOrderByID) to receive the complete data. The problem is that this process is taking more than 10 seconds and I want to use Multithreading to have a shorter time.

For iteration of my list.

```
// My list with ~200 registers
for (Order order: orderList.getID()) {
      OrderRestVO response = findOrderByID(order.getID); //Calling an API method
}
```

My question is, how do I utilize multi-threading to optimize my search?

Comment: How can this simple code be so slow ?

Comment: I'm guessing you are going and hitting the DB with each ID and getting the data back ?? if so, why not just create a new call where you pass all the ID's and get back a list of OrderRestVO ...it will be faster than multithreading as you will still have to do multiple DB hits in the case of multiThreading whereas here you do just one

Comment: But I can't create a new webservice in this moment and this is my only solutions in my application.

Comment: @rohitthomas while your comment generally makes sense, the OP is telling explicitly that it is a REST API call.

Comment: So if you still use multi-threading it will still take time as a Lock is created on the table when you read the record....So if you wish to make a significant improvement i suggest doing a dirty read in sql...there are draw backs...but as long as you are just reading the value it should'nt be an issue